# Не работают скрипты на iphone

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone

Постоянно сталкиваюсь с тем, что некоторые скрипты не работают на iPhone.
В частности сейчас столкнулся с такой проблемой, следующий скрипт не отрабатывает на iPhone разных моделей (проблема точно не в браузере, проверял в safari, chrome, yandex browser):

```
$(document).on('click', '.modal-layer__closure', function () {
    $(this).closest('.modal-layer').removeClass('active');
    return false;
});
```

Может кто-то может пояснить причину и как впредь избежать подобных проблем?

Comment: В чем ошибка..?

Comment: По клику должно закрываться модальное окно, и всё отлично работает на всех устройствах кроме iphone, а как узнать причину сбоя я не знаю

Comment: Возможно у вас просто выключен javascript. А так, для отладки. почитайте, как отлаживать сайты через телефон.

Comment: javascript не выключен, большая часть скриптов работает нормально, кроме нескольких слушателей вроде приведенного выше

Comment: Данный код не зависит от телефона, а от версии библиотеки `jquery`. Скачайте `debugger` и смотрите в чем ошибка, а гадать никто не будет.

Comment: Я не просил гадать, но надеялся что кто-то сталкивался с подобной проблемой. У меня нет айфона чтобы постоянно тестировать, а устанавливать дебагеры на чужой айфон мне никто не даст, выкручиваюсь как могу

Comment: Один из способов избежания подобных проблем - писать на чистом JavaScript и использовать Babel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я нашёл причину ошибки:

на **iOS** устройствах событие **click** работает только для ссылок и (возможно) для элементов с атрибутом **tabindex**.

Я же навешивал слушатель на **div** элемент.

Оптимальный вариант: использовать для мобильной версии события **touchstart**, **touchend** и т.п.

Comment: даже на div можно вешать событие jquery click, достаточно добавить css свойство cursor:pointer

Comment: Возможно, но это совсем не очевидно, поэтому лучше использовать 'touchend'